# Guest users do not see records on my public Experience Cloud site

Tags: permissions, experience-cloud

I have my experience cloud site setup as public, so users can view the site without login in. I followed all the necessary steps to make sure guest users could see the records, but when I view the site, there were no records displayed. I'm using a Salesforce dev org where I have 20 custom object records, which should be visible to the guest user.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Activated my Experience Cloud site
2. In the site builder I checked the box "Guest users can see and interact with the site without logging in" Settings
3. On the Guest User profile, I gave read permission to the custom object and its field.
4. On the Org Wide Defaults, I set "Default External Access" to "Public Read Only" for the custom object.
5. I created a sharing rule for the custom object for "Guest user access, based on criteria"
6. Then the final step: I go to setup -> Guest User Sharing Rule Access Report, the report shows that the records are visible for the guest user, but still no records are displayed on the Experience Cloud site.

What am I missing here?